# нужно свести подобные числа массиве (c++)

Tags: c++, массивы, сортировка

Есть отсортированный в порядке убывания массив. Как сделать, чтобы два одинаковых элемента исчезали и вместо них вписывать один на 1 больше.

то есть примерно так

```
[12 8 8 6  4 3 3] =>
[12 9 6 5 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Примерно [так](http://ideone.com/QArC5e).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main ()
{
  std::vector <int> v = {12, 8, 8, 6, 4, 3, 3};
  for(size_t i=0; i<v.size()-1; i++)
  {
      if(v[i]==v[i+1])
      {
          v[i]++;
          v.erase(v.begin()+i+1);
          i=0;
      }
  }
  for(auto&x:v)std::cout << x << " ";

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В общем то если кто-то тоже будет искать что-то подобное, помогли на англоязычной версии.

```
vector<int> v(c, c + mn);
```

где `с` - массив, `mn` - длинна.

```
for (int i = 0; i < v.size() - 1; i++)
{
    if (v[i] == v[i + 1])
    {
        while (i + 1<v.size() && v[i + 1] == v[i])
            v.erase(v.begin() + i + 1);
        v[i]++;
        i = 0;
    }
}
for (auto&x : v)std::cout << x << ".";
```